# Unable to authenticate cluster user: HORNETQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER

Tags: jboss7.x, wildfly, hornetq, wildfly-8

I am getting following error in WildFly-8.2.0.Final domain mode. This error comes when I start second node.

```
ERROR [org.hornetq.core.server] (default I/O-1) HQ224018: Failed to create session: HornetQClusterSecurityException[errorType=CLUSTER_SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=HQ119099: Unable to authenticate cluster user: HORNETQ.CLUSTER.ADMIN.USER]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed by adding 
${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:@password@} to subsystem in standalone.xml.